# Display passed Test names in Android Studio Unit Test - JUnit5 with Kotlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, junit5

I'm learning on JUnit5 with Kotlin, and I wrote a test code with special names as function names using the back tick but nothing was displayed for passed tests. I used the annotation of `@DisplayName("something")` that didn't display any name of passed tests.

i always get this empty list of tests

[image]

here is the code

```
@DisplayName("A special test case")
class DisplayNameTest {

    @Test
    @DisplayName("First Test")
    fun `First Test with normal name`() {}

    @Test
    @DisplayName("(╯°Д°)╯")
    fun `Second Test with Special Characters`() {}

    @Test
    @DisplayName("&#128522;")
    fun `Test name including an Emoji`() {}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click that check mark above the results to show passing tests

[image: The button enabled and several passed tests displayed]

It's just that usually, you only care about the failing ones!

Comment: weird, I thought i clicked it and nothing happened.... but now it works.. thank you!

Comment: @KotlinStudent make sure you're running the right tests too - if all your tests pass, and you do the "re-run failing tests" option, because there are no failed tests to run there won't be any test results to show. That might be why nothing showed up when you toggled that button on